# Server response login error!

Tags: shell-script, shell, programming

This is the script i build

```
for i in `cat cain.txt`
do
uuid=$(curl   -X POST -H "ACCEPT-LANGUAGE:en"   -H "Content-Type:application/json"   -H "Accept: application/json" -d  '{"username":"TheUserName"}'  H) 
> final.txt
fuid=$(echo "$uuid" | sed -nE 's/.*"serviceUuid":"(.*)","user.*/\1/p' >>  final.txt)
eval $fuid
echo $fuid

service_uuid=$(cat final.txt)
password=$(sed -n 1p cain.txt)
echo $service_uuid
echo $password

login=$(curl -X POST -H "ACCEPT-LANGUAGE:en"  -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8"  -H "Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate"   -H "Accept: application/json"  -H "Connection: keep-alive" -d  '{"serviceUuid":"${service_uuid}","password":"${password}"}'  HereTheUrl)

echo "$login"
if [ "$login" = "STATUS_OK" ]
then
echo "Password: $password"
break
else
echo "Trying: $password"
fi
done
```

When i run it the server response is:

{"status":{"code":"NOT_AUTHENTICATED","message":"HereTheUrl"},"body":{}}

How to fix that?

(the response for password error need to be "ERROR" not "NOT_AUTHENTICATED")

Comment: Without understanding the API it's going to be a bit difficult to say. It looks like the server is responding that authentication failed. This is deeply in the domain of the application though.

Comment: @Bratchley I think i know what happens...the first one response is good [STATUS_OK] when i send the username...then starts the error...i think can be that i don't send the username everytime but only one time then i try password but without sending before username.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem.
The problem was created for an syntax error.

The error was about the position of the " and the '
Just needed to change the ' in " and then it works.

```
login=$(curl -X POST -H "ACCEPT-LANGUAGE:en"  -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8"  -H "Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate"   -H "Accept: application/json"  -H "Connection: keep-alive" -d  "{"serviceUuid":"${service_uuid}","password":"${password}"}"  HereTheUrl)
```

and

```
uuid=$(curl   -X POST -H "ACCEPT-LANGUAGE:en"   -H "Content-Type:application/json"   -H "Accept: application/json" -d  "{"username":"TheUserName"}"
```